# Access nth child of ViewChildren Querylist (Angular)

Tags: angular, viewchild

I'm trying to access the nth child of a viewchildren querylist.

Below is my TS:

```
@ViewChildren(PopoverDirective) popovers: QueryList<PopoverDirective>;
console.log(this.popovers)
```

The console.log shows changes, first, last, length and _results.

How can I access the nth child (i.e., 3rd, instead of first)?

When I try to do this with _results (i.e., this.popovers._results[2]), I get an error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> There are actually a couple of methods which you can access a particular inside you `QueryLists`

**1st method: .filter()**

*You can also use **.map and .reduce** based on your preferences*

```
// Since if you have 3 items in an array, the counting starts at 0, so 1 is the 2nd element
const elementTwo = this.popovers.filter((element, index) => index === 1);


// Or if you want to be specific based on the data inside the PopoverDirective
// and if that PopoverDirective has an @Input() name, you can access it by:
const elementTwo = this.popovers.filter((element, index) => element.name === 'John');
```

**2nd method: .forEach()**

```
// You can perform any action inside the .forEach() which you can readily access the element
this.popovers.forEach((element, index) => console.log(element));
```

**3rd method: first and last**

```
this.popovers.first         // This will give you the first element of the Popovers QueryList

this.popovers.last          // This will give the last element of the Popovers QueryList
```

**Raw Array List: .toArray()**

```
this.popovers.toArray();    // This will give you the list of popovers caught by your QueryList
```

Comment: Does the filter not return an array?

Comment: Hi @QianChen, the filter do returns an array.

Comment: Many thanks for clarifying. What if I want to iterate over a `QueryList<ElementRef>`? Does that change anything? (I'm having trouble doing that now, but might've missed something obvious).

Comment: Hi @Crowdpleasr, it's still the same you can apply those even if we were to querylist in element. Have attached Stackblitz demo for your reference - You can check the console.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-viewchildren-querylist

Comment: `toArray()` creates a slice of the underlying querylist results everytime. Something to keep in mind for performance.

Comment: IMO @rafi's answer is a better solution, since `find` returns _the one item at index_ instead of an array containing an item.

Comment: @KShewengger Do you have an explanation on the reason why we shall not do `popovers[0]` on a `queryList` ?

Comment: Hi @RaphaëlBalet, this may be late but to answer your question, accessing the query list immediately with popovers[0] will give you undefined. Instead, use popovers.toArray()[0] to access the element on the 0 index or use .first See the link for sample:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-viewchildren-querylist-8bcbsa?devToolsHeight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 9):

Accessing by index is possible through `Find`

```js
  @ViewChildren(PopoverDirective) popovers: QueryList<PopoverDirective>;

  public getByIndex(x: number) {
    return this.popovers.find((_, i) => i == x)
  }
```

Comment: I actually found that this method is faster than calling `toArray()`. `toArray()` creates a slice of the underlying query list before accessing the index. Meanwhile, `find()` operates on the original underlying query list array. So, not only is it faster, but it will save some memory.

Answer (score 5):

you can use toArray() method and then you can access by index.